# i'm getting this error: Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML. Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "0" Client: "01"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, local-storage, react-context

I'm trying to create a cart page but i keep running into this error, the error began when i added localStorage to it. I will provide the stateContext and Cart component code below.

```
"use client"
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { toast } from "react-hot-toast";

export const Context = createContext()

export const StateContext = ({ children }) => {
    const cartFromLocaleStorage = typeof window !== "undefined" && JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')) || []
    const totalQuantitiesFromLocalStorage = typeof window !== "undefined" && localStorage.getItem("totalQuantities") || 0;

    const totalPriceFromLocalStorage = typeof window !== "undefined" && localStorage.getItem("totalPrice") || 0;

    const [toggleSearch, setToggleSearch] = useState(false)
    const [showCart, setShowCart] = useState(false);
    const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState(cartFromLocaleStorage);
    const [totalPrice, setTotalPrice] = useState(totalPriceFromLocalStorage);
    const [totalQuantities, setTotalQuantities] = useState(totalQuantitiesFromLocalStorage);
    const [qty, setQty] = useState(1);

    let foundProduct

    useEffect(() => {
        const setCart = () => {
          typeof window !== "undefined" && localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cartItems));
          typeof window !== "undefined" && localStorage.setItem("totalQuantities", totalQuantities);
          typeof window !== "undefined" && localStorage.setItem("totalPrice", totalPrice);
        };
        setCart();
      }, [cartItems, totalQuantities, totalPrice])

    const handleSearchToggle = () => {
        setToggleSearch((prev) => !prev)
    }

    const onAdd = (product, quantity) => {
        const productInCart = cartItems.find((item) => item._id === product._id)

        if (productInCart){
            const newCartItems = cartItems.map((item) => {
                if(item._id === product._id) return {
                    ...item, quantity: item.quantity + quantity
                }
                return item;
            })
            setCartItems(newCartItems)
        } else{
            //product.quantity = quantity
            setCartItems((prev) => [...prev, { ...product, quantity: quantity }]);
        }
        setTotalPrice((prev) => prev + product.price * quantity)
        setTotalQuantities((prev) => prev + quantity)
        toast.success(`${qty} ${product.title} added to the cart.`)
    }

    const onRemove = (product) => {
        foundProduct = cartItems.find((item) => {item._id === product._id})
        const newCartItems = cartItems.filter((item) => item._id !== product._id)
        setCartItems(newCartItems)
        setTotalPrice((prev) => prev - product.quantity * product.price)
        setTotalQuantities((prev) => prev - product.quantity)
        localStorage.removeItem('cart')
        localStorage.removeItem('totalQuantitiesFromLocalStorage')
        localStorage.removeItem('totalPriceFromLocalStorage')
    }

    const onCartItemQuantity = (id, type) => {
        const foundProduct = cartItems.find((item) => item._id === id);

        if (!foundProduct) return;

        if (type === "inc") {
        setCartItems((prev) =>
            prev.map((item) =>
            item._id === id ? { ...item, quantity: item.quantity + 1 } : item
            )
        );
        setTotalPrice((prev) => prev + foundProduct.price);
        setTotalQuantities((prev) => prev + 1);
        } else if (type === "dec" && foundProduct.quantity > 1) {
        setCartItems((prev) =>
            prev.map((item) =>
            item._id === id ? { ...item, quantity: item.quantity - 1 } : item
            )
        );
        setTotalPrice((prev) => prev - foundProduct.price);
        setTotalQuantities((prev) => prev - 1);
        }
    };

    
    const incQty = () => {
        setQty((prev) => {prev + 1})
    }
    const decQty = () => {
        setQty((prev) => {
        if(prev - 1 < 1) return 1;
        return prev - 1})
    }

    return(
        <Context.Provider
            value={{
                showCart,
                setShowCart,
                onAdd,
                incQty,
                decQty,
                onCartItemQuantity,
                onRemove,
                totalQuantities,
                totalPrice,
                cartItems,
                qty, 
                toggleSearch,
                setToggleSearch,
                handleSearchToggle
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </Context.Provider>
    )
}


export const useStateContext = () => useContext(Context);
```

That is the StateContext code and here is the Cart component code:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { AiOutlineMinus, AiOutlinePlus, AiOutlineLeft, AiOutlineShopping } from 'react-icons/ai';
import { RxCross2 } from 'react-icons/rx'
import Image from 'next/image';
import toast from 'react-hot-toast';

import { useStateContext } from '@context/StateContext';

const  Cart = () => {

    const { onCartItemQuantity, onRemove, setShowCart, totalQuantities, totalPrice, cartItems } = useStateContext()
  
    return (
    <div className='cart-wrapper transition ease-in-out delay-150'>
        <div className='cart-container transition ease-in-out delay-150'>
            <div className='flex flex-row justify-between ps-2.5'>
                <h1 className='text-[#452b1a] text-xs font-bold'>CART</h1>
                <button className='text-[#452b1a] text-2xl font-bold' onClick={() => setShowCart(false)}><RxCross2  /></button>
            </div>

            {cartItems.length < 1 && (
                <div className='items-center justify-center flex h-5/6 '>
                    <h1 className='text-[15px] font-semibold text-[#452b1a]'>YOUR CART IS EMPTY</h1>
                </div>
            )}

            {cartItems.length >= 1 && cartItems.map((item) => (
                <div className='flex gap-x-3 p-5 overflow-y-scroll' key={item._id}>
                    <Image src={item.image[0]} width={100} height={150}/>
                    <div className='flex flex-col items-start gap-y-1'>
                        <div>
                            <h1 className='text-sm font-semibold text-[#452b1a]'>{item.title}</h1>
                            <p className='text-[#452b1a] text-xs font-light'>${item.price}</p>
                            <p className='text-[#452b1a] text-xs font-thin pt-1'>XS</p>
                        </div>

                        <div className='mt-4 flex flex-row gap-2 align-middle'>
                            <span className="text-xs font-thin my-auto" onClick={() => onCartItemQuantity(item._id, 'dec') }>
                                <AiOutlineMinus />
                            </span>
                            <span className="text-xs font-thin text-[#452b1a]" onClick="">{item.quantity}</span>
                            <span className="text-xs font-thin text-[#452b1a] my-auto" onClick={() => onCartItemQuantity(item._id, 'inc') }><AiOutlinePlus /></span>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <button className='text-[12px] font-thin underline hover:decoration text-[#452b1a]  transition ease-out delay-150' onClick={() => onRemove(item)}>Remove</button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}

            

            <div className='flex flex-col w-full absolute bottom-0'>
                <p className='text-xs font-thin text-[#452b1a] py-2 top-[490px] text-center border-y-[#452b1a] border'>
                    <span>You are eligible for free shipping!</span>
                </p>
                <div className="flex justify-between ms-1 me-2 py-1">
                    <div className='flex flex-col'>
                        <span className='flex flex-col text-[#452b1a] font-medium text-[12px] text'>
                            CART
                            <span className='font-medium'>{totalQuantities} items</span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                        <h2 className='text-[#452b1a] font-medium text-right flex text-[12px] flex-col'>
                            SUBTOTAL
                            <span>₦{totalPrice}</span>
                        </h2>
                </div>

                <button className='bg-[#452b1a] mx-1 hover:bg-[#fff] hover:border hover:text-black text-white border-[#452b1a] py-2 text-[12px] font-semibold'>CHECKOUT</button>
                <p className='text-[10px] text-[#452b1a] text-center font-bold'>Shipping & taxes calculated at checkout</p>
            </div>

        </div>
        
    </div>
  )
}

export default  Cart
```

it's working but I get this error when I add the item to the cart and refresh the page i get this error:

Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "0" Client: "1"

and sometimes the code break and instead of my totalquantities showing 1, it will display 01 and instead of 2, it will display 011, this happens sometimes and when i hard refresh multiple times it display normally again

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72673362/error-text-content-does-not-match-server-rendered-html